# Is it possible to create a casted index on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, casting

So I tried to create a casted index on a table (The data type of my column is `char(64)`), my query is like that:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_column_name ON table (CAST(column_name AS INTEGER));
```

But it didn't work, It gives the error `SQL Error [1064] [42000]` which means that I have an error in my syntax, I tried so many syntaxes but still doesn't work, Can anyone have a clear idea about what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Is there some reason for using`CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your statement.

1. `INTEGER` is not correct datatype which can be used in CAST(). Use SIGNED or UNSIGNED instead.
2. The expression must be enclosed with separate parenthesis.

So correct syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name VARCHAR(64));
```

```
CREATE INDEX idx_column_name ON table_name ( (CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED)) );
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| table_name | CREATE TABLE `table_name` ( `column_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, KEY `idx_column_name` ((cast(`column_name` as unsigned))) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zLsbEArO)

Comment: Thanks, @Akina I tried this but still have the same syntax issue

Comment: @amel You need the version 8.0.17 or higher. Fiddle added.

Comment: Yes, I see that is the source of my problem I'm using version 5.7.31, Thanks @Akina